# codeigniter html email changing characters

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-email

i have a problem with emails the html is ok but when i open them there are errors in the text and the links some chars where changed into = like

```
Thanks for joining . your log=n details are here ma=e sure you keep them safe.
To verify your email address, please follow this link:

 Finish your registration...

Link doesn't work? Copy the following link to your browser address bar:  http://www.myurl.com/dev=l/panel/auth/activate/123131/123131

Please verify your email within 123131 hours, otherwise your registration =ill become invalid and you will have to register again.
```

every image and link even the text is borken up 
i was thinkin that it has someting to do with {unwrap} but did not help

this is the config/email.php

```
$config['email_notification']['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['email_notification']['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.live.com';
$config['email_notification']['smtp_user'] = 'xxxxx';
$config['email_notification']['smtp_pass'] = 'xxxxxxx';
$config['email_notification']['smtp_port'] = '587';
$config['email_notification']['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['email_notification']['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['email_notification']['wordwrap'] = false;
$config['email_notification']['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';
```

this is the controller

```
 $this->load->library('email');



    $this->email->initialize($this->config->item('email_notification'));
    $this->email->subject('Email Test');

    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('xxxxxx'); // change it to yours
    $this->email->to('xxxxx');
    $this->email->subject('Email Test');

    $data=array(
        'site_name'=>'tralalalal',
        'user_id'=>'123131',
        'new_email_key'=>'123131',
        'activation_period'=>'123131',
        'email'=>'123131',
        'title'=>'123131',

    );
    $this->email->message($this->load->view('email/activate_account/en',$data,true));
```

the email body is

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    /* Client-specific Styles */
#outlook a{padding:0;} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" button. */
body{width:100% !important;} .ReadMsgBody{width:100%;} .ExternalClass{width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
body{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;} /* Prevent Webkit platforms from changing default text sizes. */

    /* Reset Styles */
body{margin:0; padding:0;}
img{border:0; height:auto; line-height:100%; outline:none; text-decoration:none;}
table td{border-collapse:collapse;}
#backgroundTable{height:100% !important; margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
```

thanks

Comment: i think its a problem with _prep_quoted_printable

Answer (score 4):

i found the answer so if anyone have the same problem

there is why

> There are two limits that this standard places on the number of
>   characters in a line. Each line of characters MUST be no more than
>   998 characters, and SHOULD be no more than 78 characters, excluding
>   the CRLF.
>
> The 998 character limit is due to limitations in many
>   implementations    which send, receive, or store Internet Message
>   Format messages that    simply cannot handle more than 998 characters
>   on a line. Receiving    implementations would do well to handle an
>   arbitrarily large number    of characters in a line for robustness
>   sake. However, there are so    many implementations which (in
>   compliance with the transport    requirements of [RFC2821]) do not
>   accept messages containing more    than 1000 character including the
>   CR and LF per line, it is important    for implementations not to
>   create such messages.
>
> The more conservative 78 character recommendation is to accommodate
>   the many implementations of user interfaces that display these
>   messages which may truncate, or disastrously wrap, the display of
>   more than 78 characters per line, in spite of the fact that such
>   implementations are non-conformant to the intent of this
>   specification (and that of [RFC2821] if they actually cause
>   information to be lost). Again, even though this limitation is put on 
>   messages, it is encumbant upon implementations which display messages

and this is where you change the code to overwrite this limit 
system/libraries/email.php

ORGINAL

```
protected function _prep_quoted_printable($str, $charlim = '')
{
    // Set the character limit
    // Don't allow over 76, as that will make servers and MUAs barf
    // all over quoted-printable data
    if ($charlim == '' OR $charlim > '76')
    {
        $charlim = '76';
    }
```

QUICK FIX :)

```
protected function _prep_quoted_printable($str, $charlim = '')
{
    // Set the character limit
    // Don't allow over 76, as that will make servers and MUAs barf
    // all over quoted-printable data
    if ($charlim == '' OR $charlim > '76')
    {
        $charlim = '200';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the _prep_quoted_printable function.  Luckily there is a native PHP version of this function as of v5.3

I was able to solve a similar issue by replacing instances of _prep_quoted_printable in the Email class with the PHP native function quoted_printable_encode.

This amounted to my _build_message() looking like this:

```
    /**
 * Build Final Body and attachments
 *
 * @access  protected
 * @return  void
 */
protected function _build_message()
{
    if ($this->wordwrap === TRUE  AND  $this->mailtype != 'html')
    {
        $this->_body = $this->word_wrap($this->_body);
    }

    $this->_set_boundaries();
    $this->_write_headers();

    $hdr = ($this->_get_protocol() == 'mail') ? $this->newline : '';
    $body = '';

    switch ($this->_get_content_type())
    {
        case 'plain' :

            $hdr .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" . $this->charset . $this->newline;
            $hdr .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: " . $this->_get_encoding();

            if ($this->_get_protocol() == 'mail')
            {
                $this->_header_str .= $hdr;
                $this->_finalbody = $this->_body;
            }
            else
            {
                $this->_finalbody = $hdr . $this->newline . $this->newline . $this->_body;
            }

            return;

        break;
        case 'html' :

            if ($this->send_multipart === FALSE)
            {
                $hdr .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=" . $this->charset . $this->newline;
                $hdr .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable";
            }
            else
            {
                $hdr .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"" . $this->_alt_boundary . "\"" . $this->newline . $this->newline;

                $body .= $this->_get_mime_message() . $this->newline . $this->newline;
                $body .= "--" . $this->_alt_boundary . $this->newline;

                $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" . $this->charset . $this->newline;
                $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: " . $this->_get_encoding() . $this->newline . $this->newline;
                $body .= $this->_get_alt_message() . $this->newline . $this->newline . "--" . $this->_alt_boundary . $this->newline;

                $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=" . $this->charset . $this->newline;
                $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . $this->newline . $this->newline;
            }

            // $this->_finalbody = $body . $this->_prep_quoted_printable($this->_body) . $this->newline . $this->newline;
            $this->_finalbody = $body . quoted_printable_encode($this->_body) . $this->newline . $this->newline;


            if ($this->_get_protocol() == 'mail')
            {
                $this->_header_str .= $hdr;
            }
            else
            {
                $this->_finalbody = $hdr . $this->_finalbody;
            }


            if ($this->send_multipart !== FALSE)
            {
                $this->_finalbody .= "--" . $this->_alt_boundary . "--";
            }

            return;

        break;
        case 'plain-attach' :

            $hdr .= "Content-Type: multipart/".$this->multipart."; boundary=\"" . $this->_atc_boundary."\"" . $this->newline . $this->newline;

            if ($this->_get_protocol() == 'mail')
            {
                $this->_header_str .= $hdr;
            }

            $body .= $this->_get_mime_message() . $this->newline . $this->newline;
            $body .= "--" . $this->_atc_boundary . $this->newline;

            $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" . $this->charset . $this->newline;
            $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: " . $this->_get_encoding() . $this->newline . $this->newline;

            $body .= $this->_body . $this->newline . $this->newline;

        break;
        case 'html-attach' :

            $hdr .= "Content-Type: multipart/".$this->multipart."; boundary=\"" . $this->_atc_boundary."\"" . $this->newline . $this->newline;

            if ($this->_get_protocol() == 'mail')
            {
                $this->_header_str .= $hdr;
            }

            $body .= $this->_get_mime_message() . $this->newline . $this->newline;
            $body .= "--" . $this->_atc_boundary . $this->newline;

            $body .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"" . $this->_alt_boundary . "\"" . $this->newline .$this->newline;
            $body .= "--" . $this->_alt_boundary . $this->newline;

            $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" . $this->charset . $this->newline;
            $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: " . $this->_get_encoding() . $this->newline . $this->newline;
            $body .= $this->_get_alt_message() . $this->newline . $this->newline . "--" . $this->_alt_boundary . $this->newline;

            $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=" . $this->charset . $this->newline;
            $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . $this->newline . $this->newline;

            // $body .= $this->_prep_quoted_printable($this->_body) . $this->newline . $this->newline;
            $body .= quoted_printable_encode($this->_body) . $this->newline . $this->newline;
            $body .= "--" . $this->_alt_boundary . "--" . $this->newline . $this->newline;

        break;
    }

    $attachment = array();

    $z = 0;

    for ($i=0; $i < count($this->_attach_name); $i++)
    {
        $filename = $this->_attach_name[$i];
        $basename = basename($filename);
        $ctype = $this->_attach_type[$i];

        if ( ! file_exists($filename))
        {
            $this->_set_error_message('lang:email_attachment_missing', $filename);
            return FALSE;
        }

        $h  = "--".$this->_atc_boundary.$this->newline;
        $h .= "Content-type: ".$ctype."; ";
        $h .= "name=\"".$basename."\"".$this->newline;
        $h .= "Content-Disposition: ".$this->_attach_disp[$i].";".$this->newline;
        $h .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$this->newline;

        $attachment[$z++] = $h;
        $file = filesize($filename) +1;

        if ( ! $fp = fopen($filename, FOPEN_READ))
        {
            $this->_set_error_message('lang:email_attachment_unreadable', $filename);
            return FALSE;
        }

        $attachment[$z++] = chunk_split(base64_encode(fread($fp, $file)));
        fclose($fp);
    }

    $body .= implode($this->newline, $attachment).$this->newline."--".$this->_atc_boundary."--";


    if ($this->_get_protocol() == 'mail')
    {
        $this->_finalbody = $body;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->_finalbody = $hdr . $body;
    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a closed environment with Outlook and no expectation of sending to another mail client.

Similar result but different version of codeigniter.
The one I have has a wrapchars variable to allow it to change.
The thing is it was using a hardcoded 76 in _prep_quoted_printable.
I changed the 76 to

```
    $this->wrapchars
```

and all became good in the world.